AMI line coding auto-correlation
I want to verify the calculation for $R_{xx}(n) = E[a_i a^*_{i+n}]$ for Alternate Mark Inversion:
Because we have $R(n=0) = 1/2, R(n=2) = |\mu|^2 = 0 , R(n=1) = R(n=-1) = -1/4$
Alas I want to know how did we derive these results, thanks.

I don't think that $R(0)=0$ really holds. Could you try to correct the numbers in your question?

The only way for $R(0)=0$ is for the entire signal to be 0 everywhere, in which case you couldn't get $R(k) \neq 0 ; \forall k \neq 0$.

@MattL. thank you i corrected it, can i see the logic behind the values?

@Baddioes better now? ty

If you assume that zeros and ones are equally likely, the autocorrelation at lag zero must be
$$R[0]=E\{X^2_k\}=\frac12\cdot 1 + \frac12\cdot 0=\frac12$$
because $X^2_k=1$ with probability $\frac12$ or it is $0$, also with probability $\frac12$.
For lag $1$ you have four (equally likely) possibilities for two adjacent bits: $00$, $01$, $10$, and $11$. In the first three cases, the product $X_kX_{k+1}$ equals zero, and in the last case the product $X_kX_{k+1}$ equals $-1$ due to the alternating sign property. Hence,
$$R[1]=R[-1]=\frac34\cdot 0 + \frac14\cdot (-1)=-\frac14$$
You can continue like this for lags greater than $1$, and you'll find that $R[n]=0$ for $|n|>1$ due to the alternating signs of non-zero symbols.

Two questions concerning this & i will gracefully take your beautiful answer, 1) what is a lag? 2) i dont really get the approach you did for the second case n = 1., because $X_k X_{k+1} \in {0, -1}$ and we have 4 values for $X_i \in { 1^+, 1^- , 0^+ , 0^- }$

@MOHAMEDSALHI: By lag I mean the index of the autocorrelation function: lag $n$ means $R[n]=E{X_kX_{k+n}}$. The four possibilities for case $n=1$ are just the bit combinations, not the actual symbols. You're right that $X_kX_{k+1}$ equals $0$ or $-1$. And it equals $-1$ with probability $\frac14$, that's how you arrive at the equation for $R[1]$ in my answer.

sorry for my question but, how did you derive that combination? also does R(0) = R(2)?

@MOHAMEDSALHI: Combining two bits gives 4 combinations, right? Concerning $R[n]$ for $|n|>1$, in the last sentence I state that they're all zero. The only non-zero values are $R[0]$ and $R[1]=R[-1]$.

but we have 4 bits instead?

@MOHAMEDSALHI: For $R[1]$ you have to look at two neighboring values, not 4.

Yes so if we suppose $X_i = 1^+$ then the only possible outcome for $X_{i+1} = 1^- , 0^+$ thus $X_i \cdot X_{i+1} \in {0, -1}$

@MOHAMEDSALHI: True, 0 with probability 3/4, and -1 with probability 1/4, that's how we arrive at the value -1/4.

Yes i know that it is 3/4, but i cant somehow make up a rigorous proof for it, because i cant see the way to make way to write what you did, (00, 01, 10, 11) using the signed values

@MOHAMEDSALHI: With the first three it doesn't matter what sign you have because their product is always zero. The product of the last one (11) is always -1 because one of the two ones must be inverted by the AMI coding rules, doesn't matter which one.
